# Bootstrap searchbox pull-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a searchbox on the right next to another container with pull-left:

```
<div>
  <div class="pull-left"><span>SOME TEXT</span></div>
  <div class="pull-right">  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootply link:
[LINK](https://www.bootply.com/tT5tGL95sf)
It does not work the intended way.

Comment: instead of `class="pull-right"` use `class="right"`

Comment: I want to have the searchbox as far on the right as possible, not just beside the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the grid, you don't need the pull-right class.

As for your example, some text is given `col-*-8` and your search bar is given `col-*-4` it will place your search in the right.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-*-8">
      Some Text
    </div>

    <div class="col-*-4">
      BUTTON
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This [Documentation](http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFrbkhWP0rM) are really informative and you can anytime check the [Bootstrap Official Grid Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Here is the [Solution](https://www.bootply.com/c5eFg0egCT).

Comment: If you find this answer correct, please mark it correct as well. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Glad I could help, please check the documentations I added in the edits. That might help as well.